# calling akka scheduler from callback function running on thread outside of akka

Tags: multithreading, scala, akka

How can I call the akka scheduler from a thread outside of the Akka system?

I have an actor that will instantiate a few java classes, which have callbacks that are run on their own threads. I'd like to schedule execution from these callbacks:

pseudocode:

```
class GPIOActor extends Actor with PubSubActor {

  class DebouncerListener(pin: Pin) extends GpioPinListenerDigital {

    override def stateChangeEvent(event: GpioPinDigitalStateChangeEvent) {
      if (notAlreadyWaitingForBounceToFinish)
        context.system.scheduler.scheduleOnce(debouncePollPeriod, new Runnable() {
          def run(): Unit = {
            if (stillBouncing) {
              context.system.scheduler.scheduleOnce(debouncePollPeriod, this)(context.dispatcher)
            } else self ! PinStateChangeEvent(pin.getValue)
          }
        }      
    })(context.dispatcher)
  }

  val myPin = GPIOPinListener(RapiPin)

  myPin.registerCallback(new DebouncerListener(myPin))

  (...)

  def receive: Receive = {
    case PinStateChangeEvent(newValue) => notifySubscribers(newValue)
  }

}
```

Comment: Why don't you write listeners as just message forwarders and move logic to actor itself?

Comment: These events happen at a rate of thousand of times per second for short bursts, I need to filter them, and just forward the last state

Comment: You can model filter-then-forward-last-state logic as actor too.